# How to create dynamic introduction_screen in Flutter with introduction_screen package package link in description

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**How to create dynamic introduction_screen in Flutter with introduction_screen package**.

Means We are pass 3 screen in api. introduction_screen 3 pages.

We are pass 4 screen in api. introduction_screen 4 pages.

Package Link:
https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen

***Api Like this (3 screen):***

```
[

{
"name_Title": "title name",
"description" "Description"
},

{
"name_Title": "title name",
"description" "Description"
},

{
"name_Title": "title name",
"description" "Description"
},

],
```

***Api Like this (4 screen):***

```
[

{
"name_Title": "title name",
"description" "Description"
},

{
"name_Title": "title name",
"description" "Description"
},

{
"name_Title": "title name",
"description" "Description"
},

{
"name_Title": "title name",
"description" "Description"
},

]
```

Thank You for giving me your important time.

Comment: https://github.com/Tbsdev-Anmol/Schoolie/blob/main/lib/Screen/Intor_Page.dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am used page view builder.

Why: Because introduction_screen package had used page view. Not using page view builder.

That means page view builder property build run time widget.

And page view not build runtime widget.

that means you first define how many widget print like 5, that print 5 widget.

******Main thing we are use builder because it's draw widgets runtime like Future builder and list view builder**

**you need a code. please reply this answer below thank you**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzvxk.jpg)

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Convert your JSON into a model class and then use it to create a list of `PageViewModel`

Your model class will be:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Welcome> welcomeFromJson(String str) => List<Welcome>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Welcome.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<Welcome> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Welcome {
    Welcome({
        this.nameTitle,
        this.description,
    });

    String nameTitle;
    String description;

    factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        nameTitle: json["name_Title"] == null ? null : json["name_Title"],
        description: json["description"] == null ? null : json["description"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name_Title": nameTitle == null ? null : nameTitle,
        "description": description == null ? null : description,
    };
}
```

Comment: Please have you any code? Because I was try all method.

Comment: I have added model class in the answer

Comment: Sorry Sir this code is not working.

Comment: This is just the model class. You will have to use it to create a list of PostViewModel. Also, this is without null safety and you might be using null safety

Comment: Yes, I know Sir but sorry this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your data to `PageViewModel`:

```
// your api data
  List listViews = [
    {"name_Title": "title name", "description": "Description"},
    {"name_Title": "title name", "description": "Description"},
    {"name_Title": "title name", "description": "Description"},
    {"name_Title": "title name", "description": "Description"}
  ];

  //method to convert data to PageViewModel
  Widget PageModelView getPageViewModel(dynamic data) {
    return PageViewModel(
      title: data.name_Title,
      bodyWidget: Center(child: Text(data.description)),
    );
  }
  
  // call your introduction screen like that
  IntroductionScreen(
  pages: listViews.map((e) => getPageViewModel(e)).toList(),
  done: const Text("Done", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
  onDone: () {
    // When done button is press
  },
);
```

Comment: Sorry Sir this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Intromodel.dart**

```
class IntroModel {
  String? nameTitle;
  String? description;

  IntroModel({this.nameTitle, this.description});

  IntroModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    nameTitle = json['name_Title'];
    description = json['description'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name_Title'] = this.nameTitle;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Intropage.dart**

```
class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Isscar4;

  IntroPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.Isscar4,
  }) : super(key: key);

  List<PageViewModel> listPagesViewModel = [];

  List<IntroModel> models = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<dynamic> intro = fetchIntroApi(Isscar4);

    intro.forEach((element) {
      var element2 = element as Map<String, dynamic>;
      var cd = IntroModel.fromJson(element2);
      models.add(cd);
    });
    models.forEach((element) {
      listPagesViewModel.add(PageViewModel(
        title: element.nameTitle,
        body: element.description,
        image: Center(
          child: Image.network(
              Isscar4
                  ? "https://c.tenor.com/75ffA59OV-sAAAAC/broke-down-red-car.gif"
                  : 'https://c.tenor.com/Jd1J0SSD_3sAAAAC/bike-bicycle.gif',
              height: 175.0),
        ),
      ));
    });

    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: "/intro",
        home: Scaffold(
          body: IntroductionScreen(
            next: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(''),
            ),
            pages: listPagesViewModel,
            done: const Text('Done',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
            onDone: () {
              // When done button is press
            },
          ),
        ));
  }

  List fetchIntroApi(bool bool) {
    var four = bool;
    if (four) {
      var data =
          '[ {"name_Title": "title name1","description": "description1"}, {"name_Title": "title name2","description": "description2"}, {"name_Title": "title name3","description": "description3"}, {"name_Title": "title name4","description": "description4"} ]';
      return json.decode(data);
    } else {
      var data =
          '[ {"name_Title": "title name","description": "description1"}, {"name_Title": "title name2","description": "description2"}, {"name_Title": "title name3","description": "description3"} ]';
      return json.decode(data);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainPage.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // });

    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: "/",
        home: Scaffold(
            body:
                Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => IntroPage(Isscar4: true)),
                    );
                  },
                  child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'CAR',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        letterSpacing: 3,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                          text: '4',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                    ],
                  )
                      // IntroPage(listPagesViewModel: listPagesViewModel) //Material App,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => IntroPage(Isscar4: false)),
                    );
                  },
                  child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'BIKE',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        letterSpacing: 3,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                          text: '2',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                    ],
                  )
                      // IntroPage(listPagesViewModel: listPagesViewModel) //Material App,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ])));
  }

  MaterialApp Swithwidget(istrue) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/intro",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: IntroPage(
          Isscar4: istrue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**FullCode**

```
   import 'dart:convert';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:introduction_screen/introduction_screen.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(
        // For widgets to be able to read providers, we need to wrap the entire
        // application in a 'ProviderScope' widget.
        // This is where the state of our providers will be stored.
        MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyApp()),
      );
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // });
    
        return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            initialRoute: "/",
            home: Scaffold(
                body:
                    Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => IntroPage(Isscar4: true)),
                        );
                      },
                      child: RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                        text: 'CAR',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            letterSpacing: 3,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: '4',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                        ],
                      )
                          // IntroPage(listPagesViewModel: listPagesViewModel) //Material App,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => IntroPage(Isscar4: false)),
                        );
                      },
                      child: RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                        text: 'BIKE',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            letterSpacing: 3,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: '2',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                        ],
                      )
                          // IntroPage(listPagesViewModel: listPagesViewModel) //Material App,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ])));
      }
    
      MaterialApp Swithwidget(istrue) {
        return MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: "/intro",
          home: Scaffold(
            body: IntroPage(
              Isscar4: istrue,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Hi extends StatelessWidget {
      const Hi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Text("df"),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
      final Isscar4;
    
      IntroPage({
        Key? key,
        required this.Isscar4,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      List<PageViewModel> listPagesViewModel = [];
    
      List<IntroModel> models = [];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<dynamic> intro = fetchIntroApi(Isscar4);
    
        intro.forEach((element) {
          var element2 = element as Map<String, dynamic>;
          var cd = IntroModel.fromJson(element2);
          models.add(cd);
        });
        models.forEach((element) {
          listPagesViewModel.add(PageViewModel(
            title: element.nameTitle,
            body: element.description,
            image: Center(
              child: Image.network(
                  Isscar4
                      ? "https://c.tenor.com/75ffA59OV-sAAAAC/broke-down-red-car.gif"
                      : 'https://c.tenor.com/Jd1J0SSD_3sAAAAC/bike-bicycle.gif',
                  height: 175.0),
            ),
          ));
        });
    
        return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            initialRoute: "/intro",
            home: Scaffold(
              body: IntroductionScreen(
                next: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(''),
                ),
                pages: listPagesViewModel,
                done: const Text('Done',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                onDone: () {
                  // When done button is press
                },
              ),
            ));
      }
    
      List fetchIntroApi(bool bool) {
        var four = bool;
        if (four) {
          var data =
              '[ {"name_Title": "title name1","description": "description1"}, {"name_Title": "title name2","description": "description2"}, {"name_Title": "title name3","description": "description3"}, {"name_Title": "title name4","description": "description4"} ]';
          return json.decode(data);
        } else {
          var data =
              '[ {"name_Title1": "title name","description": "description1"}, {"name_Title": "title name2","description": "description2"}, {"name_Title": "title name3","description": "description3"} ]';
          return json.decode(data);
        }
      }
    }
    
    class IntroModel {
      String? nameTitle;
      String? description;
    
      IntroModel({this.nameTitle, this.description});
    
      IntroModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        nameTitle = json['name_Title'];
        description = json['description'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['name_Title'] = this.nameTitle;
        data['description'] = this.description;
        return data;
      }
    }
```